# How can I reshape a 3-dimensional 3024x4032x3 array into a 4-dimensional nx20x20x3 array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, matplotlib

I have an RGB image of dimensions `3,024x4,032`. I want to slide a `20x20` window over this image and arrange all of the resultant `20x20x3` in a matrix to get a 4-dimensional array.

The image was read using `matplotlib.image.imread` and, hence, is stored as a NumPy array.

Comment: So, you want a 3004x4012x20x20x3 array?  Have you done the math?  That's an array with 14 billion elements.  Are you just trying to do a convolution?

Comment: Sorry if the question wasn't clear but I want the total number of elements to remain the same. Instead of them lying in a 3-dimensional matrix, I wish to spread them over a 4-dimensional matrix with each 3-dimensional matrix inside having the dimensions 20x20x3.

Comment: I have an RGB image that I wish to divide into non-overlapping 20x20x3 windows.

Comment: Ah, so you don't want overlapping rectangles.  So that would be (150x200)x20x20x3.  Right?  That shouldn't be difficult.  You don't need to maintain the original ordering?

Comment: What do you mean by original ordering? I simply need to group the pixels in 20x20x3 non-overlapping windows... Anyways, I padded the image with zeroes to 3040x4080. Now, I was able to group it into windows of 20x20 and 40x40 but I can not seem to group the padded image into groups of 60x60. Could you kindly let me know why this might be happening?

Comment: Well, 60 does not divide evenly into 3040.